# Term for releasing software with time dependent portions still unfinished

Tags: terminology

I remember a while ago on a Stack Overflow podcast Jeff Atwood was talking about the bounty system, and he said that they released the bounty offering code before the bounty awarding code was written as the code would not be needed for a couple of weeks.

Is there a standard term for this? Agile can work in this way but it doesn’t have to. I am thinking of suggesting it to a client for something and would like to use the correct terminology along with any information backing it up as a method.

Essentially the method is to release code with some functionality incomplete as the time until the incomplete functionality is needed is less that the time it will take to develop.

Comment: As a client, I think I would have a few choice terms for the practice... "faith-based scheduling"?

Comment: Yeah: don't do this; it's not worth it.

Comment: 37signals sold their software before their billing components were completed. They completed it just-in-time.

Comment: Area51 did that.  The stuff for the commit phase was not done when the site went live.  (They kind-of got bit (just a bit) though cause some proposals shot through the first phase faster than anticipated.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is IMHO more an *opportunity* that you get sometimes, *not a method*: for example delivering a feature allowing subscription to a monthly newsletter at the start of the month and releasing the code to send the newsletter one month later. Doing this is just *smart release management* (i.e. good priorization of work). Maybe one could call that **Opportunistic Development** (that's something you'll find in Agile literature).

Comment: This is a very good point. But still dosn't help me explain to the client that it is feasible and works.

Comment: @Jeremy It appears that Mike Cohn writes that *"Stories Support Opportunistic Development"* in User Stories Applied For Agile Software Development).

Comment: Giving this the tick as it is the nearest to an official term. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeremy How do you explain to the client that you'll get anything done on time?

Answer (score 5):

Just-in-time development?  Analogous to the concept of [just-in-time inventory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_(business)) in business.

Or, less charitably, "winging it".

Comment: I like this as a phrase. See your point re winging it, but it can get features delivered earler than would be otherwise so can have value.

Comment: I think it's a terribly unwise thing to do - either it's a trivial feature in which case you're not saving much, or it's not a trivial feature in which case you're kidding yourself if you think you can guarantee implementation in a time-frame.  And you can't always tell the two apart.

Answer (score 1):

The term is **Bounty Development**.

Seriously, if you're looking into a term to what you want to do in this scenario IMHO is **incremental**, not necessarily incomplete. If you have *bounty offering code*, you don't have *incomplete bounty code*, you have *bounty offering code*.

Nothing is incomplete here: it's a deliverable (shippable increment of work) submited in a stage (a regular cadence of work) in an inspect-and-adapt manner.

> Deliver working software frequently,
>   from a couple of weeks to a couple of
>   months, with a  preference to the
>   shorter timescale.

[Source: Principles of Agile Manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/principles.html)

I would just use the term **Agile**, with a simple explanation (since using any term on earth you still need to explain it anyway): "create softwate in really small working pieces, in a shorter timescale each piece with continuous customer colaboration".

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of links that may help.  I think prototyping is closer to what you want, though I'll leave in the other links just in case you want to add some more phrases that may be useful when developing software:

- [Prototyping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_prototyping)
- [The Last Responsible Moment](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/10/the-last-responsible-moment.html)
- [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it)

Answer (score 0):

**Open Alpha or Beta (depending on completeness)**

Basically, you know that the codebase hasn't solidified for all of the features yet but you release it to the public anyway.

The 'alpha' distinction would probably fit projects that are in their initial stages of development.

The 'beta' distinction usually applies to applications that haven't matured to their first official release number (IE 1.0).

Be careful though because there are [risk inherent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066648/any-benefit-disadvantages-to-open-beta-vs-closed-beta-for-webapp/3067146#3067146) to releasing incomplete/untested code to the public.

In the case of Stack Overflow, releasing incomplete code/features isn't really a big deal because the platform is expected to be [under constant development/revision as per the user community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Suicide?

I don't think the potential gain can outweigh the risks.